# Using simple_format somehow modifies a models attribute in-place

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This is a weird one. I have a page that simple_format's a comments attribute on an instance of a model. However on the same page is a form allowing this comment to be updated. When I simple_format the attribute, the form then shows this attribute in it's modified form (i.e. with paragraph tags etc...).

I can't see how this is happening unless somehow simple_format is modifying the models attribute in-place but how could that happen when it is executed like this:

```
simple_format @warranty.comments
```

outputs:

```
<p>Here are some comments</p>
```

and further down the page in the form, or even if we just call:

```
@warranty.comments
```

we get:

```
<p>Here are some comments</p>
```

If I change it to:

```
simple_format @warranty.comments.clone
```

the behaviour goes away.

Am I missing something obvious here? I'd not expect a text helper to modify the original attribute unless it was called like `@warranty.comments.simple_format!`

Comment: What specific rails version are you using?

Comment: Thanks yes that was a bit of an oversight. Off hand I can't remember the version number but it was in the 3.0 range :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug that was [fixed earlier this month](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/f0034c75d5a9bc5065652c2fedf39250a6f1847b). The latest 3.1.0 should have the fix, but I'm not sure about the other versions.

Comment: Gah I knew it would be a bug! Tried in vain to find it in lighthouse before posting. Thanks for the heads up. It's a rails 3.0 project and I intend to upgrade to 3.1 so that's all gravy :)

Comment: Keep in mind Rails doesn't use Lighthouse anymore, they use [Github Issues](http://github.com/rails/rails/issues) instead.